# SQL Server 2012 connection string for EF5 Code First

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I created an MVC4 solution in VS 2012 with EF5, and right now I am trying to get the database to be created Code First. In the *Create* method of the controller I added `db.Database.CreateIfNotExists();`
On my machine, I also have SQL Server 2012 running, and I would like the db to be created there instead of in some SQL Express engine or other lightweight solution.

I have tried several approaches to making a correct connection string, but all has failed, and now I have no idea as to how it should look. This is how it looks now, but nothing gets created, and all i get from the `CreateIfNotExists` is an error:

- InnerException  {"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"}    System.Exception {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException}

This is what my connection string looks like:

`<add name="Tool.Models.Context" connectionString="Server=MSSQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=Tool.models.ToolDb.mdf;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

EDIT:

After struggling with this issue for almost a day, I resolved it by substituting `localhost` for `MSSQLSERVER` (Which still is the name of the instance if I look at the Configuration Manager). Thanks for the comments though. Made me think.

Comment: it seems that you have no default instance on the host named MSSQLSERVER, or - the alias MSSQLSERVER is not well defined.

Comment: Can you access this server using SSMS? Why do you have .mdf in the connection string initial catalog? You just need to specify the Database name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

localhost is the local server, not the instance, you appear to be using the default instance (called mssqlserver) and so don't need to specify the instance name, just the server name, hence why substituting MSSQLSERVER with localhost in your connection string works.

You could also use the actual name of the server in here, e.g. SERVER-01 (or whatever the actual name of your particular DB server is) and it would have the same effect.

If however you had installed a named instance on the machine, you would have to specify both the server name and the instance, e.g. localhost\instancename or server-01\instancename

Hope this helps explain why putting in localhost works.

Answer (score 0):

That's right...
 
By default, as most may already be aware, Visual Studio 2012 - ASP.NET MVC 4 templates 
will define a Default connectionString that points to a (LocalDb)v11.0 in Web.config.
In the case of Visual Studio 2010 ASP.Net MVC 4 project templates, it pointed to SQLExpress...

In my case I prefer pointing the connectionString to a specific SQL Server 2012 I use for dev.

So let's say I open SQL Management Studio and see SQLServer2012-01 name in a droplist where I want the database + tables to be created, 
well that's the name I'd normally use...

connectionString="Server=SQLServer2012-01; InitialCatalog=..."

All you have to do afterwards is straightforward - follow the steps in defining
-Enable-Migrations
-[fill your Seed method with content - if needed...]
-Add-Migration MyFirstMigration [or any migration name you want]
-Update-Database -Verbose

and you should see results updated in Server Explorer Window.

Hope it helps